# MATLAB: 3D mesh/delaunay triangulation from LIDAR

Tags: matlab, 3d, computer-vision

I am currently having a major issue with creating a 3D surface model from my LIDAR data. Currently, I can plot the 3D scatter plots as can be seen below
(3D Lidar Scatter Plot):

[image: 3D Lidar Scatter Plot]

As can be seen from the image above, some points are saturated near the boundaries.

Comment: Maybe you could give us some more details about what your problem actually is and what you would like to accomplish?

Comment: hi... I would try to make a [scatteredInterpolant](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/scattered-data-interpolation.html) and then map it to a grid

Comment: Hi, just to clarify, LIDAR we know where each points are in the real-world coordinates, from my image processing algorithm, I know the location of the hump's centre in (X,Y), I need create an algorithm that will give me the coordinates of the hump's centre in real-world coordinates. I hope it make sense...

Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a lot of experience fitting 3D point clouds from LIDAR devices to ground topography. If you provide some more details about your objective, I would be happy to offer assistance.

If you are simply looking to turn your existing point cloud into a mesh/3D raster, I would look into Matlab's GeoTiff functions ([GeoTiff Write](http://www.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/geotiffwrite.html)).

If you really need to interpolate the point cloud, I have used this GridFit function in the past [(GridFit)](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8998-surface-fitting-using-gridfit).

If you are trying to register the point cloud to existing topography, then I would recommend using an optimization routine such as FminSearch.

Answer (score 0):

I bet you a pretty penny that your LIDAR spits out data in scan order, and if it is a multiline device, it also tells you when it starts a new row.

Given the density of the image you've shown, that gives you a pretty good guess for the topology (i.e. which point is neighbor to what). That is usually good enough to get you an initial grid, which you can then massage with a variety of mesh editing techniques that is too large and varied and task-dependent to contemplate on SO - unless you tell us a lot more on what you are trying to accomplish. Delaunay is just a buzzword until you know what you want :-)

Comment: Hi thanks for replying, from LIDAR we know where each points are in the real-world coordinates, from my image processing algorithm, I know the location of the hump's centre in (X,Y), I need create an algorithm that will give me the coordinates of the hump's centre in real-world coordinates.

I hope it make sense...

Comment: This is a separate question from the page's one. I suggest you start a new one.